# What is workable serial port name for MacOS of /dev/cu.usbmodem143301 that can be accepted by Python's Pyserial?

Tags: python, macos, arduino, port

I'm trying to use Python on my Mac Catalina to communicate with my Arduino and keep getting "no such file or directory" when I input the Mac serial port /dev/cu.usbmodem1433301 (Arduino Uno) as indicated in the Arduino Tools/Port list and I run the script.  If I can't get a workable port for Python, I might as well not use it.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that the usb port on the opposite end of my mac's keyboard is the one that python can communicate with arduino through.  The port I was using was 143301 and the one that works (on the caps lock end) is 143101.  Made all the difference in the world.  Problem solved.  Life is good again.